# HTML file select and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to fetch complete the path from file select element of HTML using JavaScript. I have returned a JavaScript function, but it fetches only file name not the complete path.

How can I get the complete file path?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  It's due to security.  The browser only provides the content and the filename.

Providing the path could allow an attacker to learn things about the files on your hard drive that they want kept private.  Do you really want to let the web server know that the `kitty.png` you are uploading for your avatar was actually in `c:/pr0n/`?

No, I didn't think so.

Comment: Old version of IE browser (or on old platforms) can return full path for file in `value` property of `INPUT TYPE=FILE`. For example, IE8 on Windows XP. But IE9 in IE8 standard mode on Windows 7 return any path as _C:\fakepath\kitty.png_